# Difference between ties and ĝia

Tags: word-difference

Is there a practical difference between ties and ĝia?

Why should the following sentence use *ties*?

> a sunsistemo estas la aro de planedoj, lunoj, asteroidoj, kaj kometoj, kiu ĉirkaŭas la Sunon pro **ties** gravita kampo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So, for completeness, here is the example you're asking about:

> *La sunsistemo estas la aro de planedoj, lunoj, asteroidoj, kaj kometoj, kiu ĉirkaŭas la Sunon pro **ties** gravita kampo.*

There are a few (occasionally quirky) rules about *ties*, but I would agree that the meaning of this sentence would not change if it said *ĝia* instead of *ties.*

The relevant article in [PMEG](http://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/oa-vortecaj_vortetoj/tabelvortoj_es.html) says that *ties* is not used much, but it does include some examples where it can make a difference.

- La infano ludis kun sia pupo, kiam subite ties kapo frakasiĝis.

*Ties kapo* is the doll's head. *Ĝia kapo* is the child's. See [PMEG](http://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/oa-vortecaj_vortetoj/tabelvortoj_es.html) for more details.